# StreamWriter cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: nullpointerexception, powershell-4.0

First time user, looking for help with a script that's been driving me crazy.

Basically, I need to create a set number of files of an exact size (512KB, 2MB, 1GB) to test a SAN. These files need to be filled with random text so that the SAN doesn't catch the nuls and does actually allocate the blocks - that's also the reason I couldn't just use fsutils.
Now, I've been messing with the new-bigrandomfile by Verboon and tweaking it to my needs.

However I'm getting the error:

> ```
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
> At L:\random5.ps1:34 char:9
> +         $stream.Write($longstring)
> +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
> ```

This is the bit of code I've come up with so far; I'll add a loop at the end to copy the file I just created N times so to fill up the lun.

```ps
Set-Strictmode -Version 2.0

#temp file
$file = "c:\temp\temp.rnd"
#charset size
$charset = 64
#Block Size
$blocksize = 512
#page size
$Pagesize = 512KB
#Number of blocks in a page
$blocknum = $Pagesize / $blocksize
#Resulting/desired test file size
$filesize = 1GB
#number of pages in a file
$pagenum = $filesize / $Pagesize

# create the stream writer
$stream = System.IO.StreamWriter $file

# get a 64 element Char[]; I added the - and _ to have 64 chars
[char[]]$chars = 'azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbnAZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN0123456789-_'
1..$Pagenum | ForEach-Object {
# get a page's worth of blocks
1..$blocknum| ForEach-Object {
        # randomize all chars and...
        $rndChars = $chars | Get-Random -Count $chars.Count
        # ...join them in a string
        $string = -join $rndChars
        # repeat random string N times to get a full block string length
        $longstring = $string * ($blocksize / $charset)
        # write 1 block to file
        $stream.Write($longstring)

        # release resources by clearing string variables
        Clear-Variable string, longstring
    }
}
$stream.Close()
$stream.Dispose()
# release resources through garbage collection
[GC]::Collect()
$file.Close()
```

I've tried a gazillion variants like:

```ps
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $file
$stream = System.IO.StreamWriter $file
$stream = NewObject System.IO.StreamWriter $file
```

Of course, being a total noob at powershell, I've tried using quotes, brackets, provided the full path instead of the variable, etc. All (or most) seem to be valid syntax variants, according to a ton of examples I found online, but the output is still the same.

In case you have any improvement to suggest or alternative way to perform this task I'm all ears.

Edited the script above: just a couple of " for $file made the error disappear, - thanks LinuxDisciple; however, the file gets created but stays at 0 bytes and the script stuck in a loop.

Comment: Try `$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "c:\temp\temp.rnd"`.

Comment: Not sure why yet, but there's some type of type-coercion going on there and it will accept a literal path to a file but not a string that looks like a path to a file.

Comment: Yes, it does indeed work but I've got another error now, quite similar:

`c:\temp\temp.rnd : The term 'c:\temp\temp.rnd' is not recognized as the name of a `
`cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or `
`if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`
`At L:\random5.ps1:4 char:9`
`+ $file = c:\temp\temp.rnd`
`+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
`    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:\temp\temp.rnd:String) [], CommandNotFo `
`   undException`
`    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: Sorry, still trying to get the hang of bbcode here.
Anyway, the file gets created with the filename, but it stays empty and the script is stuck in a loop.
Also, I think I still need the variable to close the file at the end of the script, don't I? Or strea.close and stream.dispose will do?

Comment: No, apparently I don't:
`Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'Close'.`
`At L:\random5.ps1:43 char:1`
`+ $file.Close()`
Anyway it worked like a charm, it only took a bit longer than expected, it wasn't stuck after all.
Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

Fix your instantiation of StreamWriter to any of these correct variants:

```ps
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($file)
```

```ps
$stream = [IO.StreamWriter]::new($file) # the default namespace may be omitted
```

```ps
$stream = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $file
```

You can specify encoding:

```ps
$stream = [IO.StreamWriter]::new(
    $file,
    $false, # don't append
    [Text.Encoding]::ASCII
)
```

See [StreamWriter on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) for available constructors and parameters.

**PowerShell ISE** offers autocomplete with tooltips:

1. type `[streamw` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> to autocomplete the full .NET class name
2. type `]::` to see the available methods and properties
3. type `new` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> to see the constructor overrides
4. whenever needed, put the caret at the method name and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> for the tooltip

Answer (score -1):

I know nothing about powershell but a few things:

Are you sure $longstring has a value before you call stream.Write()? It sounds like it's null and that's why the error. If you can somehow output the value of $longstring to the console, it would help you make sure that it has a value.

Also, troubleshoot the code with a simplified version of your code, so that you can pinpoint what's going on, for example

```
$file = c:\temp\temp.rnd
$stream = System.IO.StreamWriter $file
$longstring = 'whatever'
$stream.Write($longstring)
```

Comment: yes, I tried outputting the value of $longstring to variable.rnd with out-file and it's there...I'll try your "debugging" method, let's see if anything comes up :)

Comment: Nope, same behavior: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: I think $stream is null. Have you tried $sw = new-object system.IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\ss2.txt") Also, try if(stream == null) (or something like that) then print "it's null". It would confirm that this variable is not instantiated correctly.

Comment: yeah, well, I used
`$longstring | out-file c:\temp\variable.rnd`
instead of the stream writer and the file is there with its content